# Swagger: Extract common generated implementation

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm using SpringBoot + Swagger (OpenApi3) + Java for my application. I use the Swagger documentation to import the API into API Gateway.

I have a couple of Java models that both have the following field: `List<MyOwnObject> objectList`.
When transformed by swagger, I get my models transformed with the same definition for the field:

```
model1:
  type: object
  properties:
    ... // other properties here
    objectList:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: #/components/schemas/MyOwnObject
model2:
  type: object
  properties:
    ... // other properties here
    objectList:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: #/components/schemas/MyOwnObject
```

Now, because of a ["feature" in API Gateway](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=798320&#798320), I need to extract these arrays definitions into a single one, referenced in the two models, but I'm not able to find a way to remodel my POJOs to accomplish it.
I require an output similar to this:

```
model1:
  type: object
  properties:
    ... // other properties here
    objectList:
      $ref: #/components/schemas/commonArray
model2:
  type: object
  properties:
    ... // other properties here
    objectList:
      $ref: #/components/schemas/commonArray
commonArray:
  type: array
    items:
      $ref: #/components/schemas/MyOwnObject
```

**What have I tried**

- I created a new POJO, containing the list variable. This works, but given that we are adding an extra variable, this affects a current-in-production API schema, which we prefer not to modify.
- I created a new POJO extending from `ArrayList<MyOwnObject>`. During generation, Swagger replaces the new object for the same `array` schema, leaving the output equal to the original.
- I've played with the `@Schema` and `@ArraySchema` Swagger annotations without luck.

Do you guys have any idea on how to solve this issue? Is it even possible to accomplish?

Thanks!